# issue with StringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch is crashing my app when I have it in the following. Does anyone know why this might be?

```
NSString* string3 = [[[[tvQ.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
    withString:@" " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString]
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"]     
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ç" withString:@"c"] 
                stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Error from X-Code:
 error: 'wholeString' not defined

Comment: Try looking at the stacktrace and messages in the console. If you don't understand them, post them here.

Comment: error is: 'wholeString' not defined

Comment: How do you define wholeString?

Comment: I don't. That's my problem. I don't know how to define this.

Comment: You only need to include the range argument if you wish to only search a certain part (ie. range) of the string; By default the method searches the whole string.

Comment: -1 Crashing your app and failing to compile are entirely different things. "\n" isn't a letter, so case-insensitive search is also meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't your 'wholeString' be a string which you have to declare before the call of this function? or, if you want to search the whole string, then shouldn't it be your tvQ.text ?

Comment: ahm, no. it's a range. so you have to declare and make the NSRange before the call...

Comment: Micko - how do you declare NSRange or "WholeString"?

Comment: Do I even need to define a range with the NSCaseInsensitiveSearch option?

Comment: I never did this before, but I think it should work with define the NSRange. Look in the documentation for "NSMakeRange". you have just to give this method two integers --> the starting point (should be 0) and the ending point (should be the string length)...

Comment: You only need to include the range argument if you wish to only search a certain part (ie. range) of the string; By default the method searches the whole string. – Felixs 2 days ago